# How can I put JavaScript code into a PDF document?

Tags: javascript, pdf

How do I insert JavaScript code into a PDF file?

I can code JavaScript, I just wish to know how to put it into a file to, for example, display the current date, use a combobox, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

JavaScript is typically tied to objects in a PDF document. For example, if you want the user to be able to print the PDF by clicking a Print button, follow the steps below:

- Add a button to the form (done under advanced editing)
- Right click on the button and go to properties
- Click the actions tab
- Under `Select Action:` choose `Run a JavaScript`
- put `print();` in the code window

Here's a link to an old (Acrobat 7.0.5) [Acrobat JavaScript Scripting
Reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20190321234218/http://www.pdfill.com/download/AcroJS.pdf) to get you started.

> Fresh Links 22/06/2020

- [Adobe Acrobat 7.0 JavaScript Scripting Reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/acro7js.pdf)
- [JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf)

Comment: Dumb question: to follow these steps, what program would I be inside of?

Comment: @JasonSwett, Adobe Acrobat

Comment: This thread is a gold mine of information on a topic that has become of great interest to me.

Comment: is there a way to do this without doing per object programming. This feels like a terrible programming practice to add code to each object

Answer (score 4):

You didn't stipulate a constraint for language, so you can use Python to achieve this. The library PyPDF2 has a class called `addJS` that works. Here is an example from the REPL:

`mypdf.addJS("this.print({bUI:true,bSilent:false,bShrinkToFit:true});")`

and [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileWriter.html) is a link to the documentation. Note, that you need to have python3 installed (2.7 is going away at the end of 2019) and then run `pip3 install PyPDF2` or similar to install the library and then load it via `import PyPDF2`. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Documentation for addJS says: "Deprecated since version 1.28.0." (see https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/PdfWriter.html?highlight=addJS#pypdf.PdfWriter.addJS)

Comment: @Alex can you update my answer then? You can see I answered this in 2019...