# Print PDF directly from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am building a list of PDFs in HTML. In the list I'd like to include a download link and a print button/link. Is there some way to directly open the Print dialog for the PDF without the user seeing the PDF or opening a PDF viewer?

Some variation of downloading the PDF into a hidden iframe and triggering it to print with JavaScript?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Based on comments below, it no longer works in modern browsers**
This question demonstrates an approach that might be helpful to you: [Silent print an embedded PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975652/silent-print-a-embedded-pdf)

It uses the `<embed>` tag to embed the PDF in the document:

```
<embed
    type="application/pdf"
    src="path_to_pdf_document.pdf"
    id="pdfDocument"
    width="100%"
    height="100%" />
```

Then you call the `.print()` method on the element in Javascript when the PDF is loaded:

```
function printDocument(documentId) {
    var doc = document.getElementById(documentId);

    //Wait until PDF is ready to print    
    if (typeof doc.print === 'undefined') {    
        setTimeout(function(){printDocument(documentId);}, 1000);
    } else {
        doc.print();
    }
}
```

You could place the embed in a hidden iframe and print it from there, giving you a seamless experience.

Comment: This solution does not work ... I am getting permission denied for Chrome , FF

Comment: This won't work if the embedded document is on a different domain.

Comment: Easier to just add javascript to the pdf to print when rendered.  This is what Google Docs does. This way either the browser loads and prints it, or the adobe plugin.

Comment: @Rahly Do you have a link to an example?

Comment: You could probably google it, but all it is, is a new script object added to the pdf, where the javascript is just "window.print()"

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640141/how-can-i-put-javascript-code-into-a-pdf-document

Comment: This does not work in Edge, `.print()` does not exist!

Comment: Yeah I'm having the issue on all browsers where the print() method is undefined. Is this method outdated? Are there any other solutions?

Comment: This no longer works. Chrome latest version, PDF on same domain. @nullability if you can't find a workaround please edit and make it clear that what's written was true in the past but no longer work so that people won't waste time trying.

Comment: not working form me, typeof doc.print is always 'undefined'  Google Chrome #71

Comment: The `doc.print` method is forever undefined !

Answer (score 57):

Here is a function to print a PDF from an iframe.

You just need to pass the URL of the PDF to the function. It will create an iframe and trigger print once the PDF is load.

Note that the function doesn't destroy the iframe. Instead, it reuses it each time the function is call. It's hard to destroy the iframe because it is needed until the printing is done, and the print method doesn't has callback support (as far as I know).

```
printPdf = function (url) {
  var iframe = this._printIframe;
  if (!this._printIframe) {
    iframe = this._printIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    iframe.onload = function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        iframe.focus();
        iframe.contentWindow.print();
      }, 1);
    };
  }

  iframe.src = url;
}
```

Comment: I give my thanks to you, as you help me solved a big problem: without `setTimeout`, print function will fail sometimes. No idea why and hope somebody will find it out.

Comment: The print method does have callback support, but it wasn't widely supported yet when you wrote this answer in 2014. It is now, though; the latest versions of all major desktop browsers support `onafterprint`. I'm a little concerned that reusing an iframe may introduce race conditions where somebody clicks on two buttons quickly and ends up printing the second PDF twice because the iframe URL had already been swapped out before the first print dialog appeared.

Comment: Chrome blocks the .print() method if the iframe contents are not from the same origin. Doesn't work unfortunately as of 2021

Answer (score 29):

You can use Print.js (`npm install print-js`). It's 128kB unpacked and you can find the docs at http://printjs.crabbly.com/.

It doesn't print on IE though, in those cases you'll have to download the PDF instead.

```
$http({
    url: "",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/pdf"
    },
    responseType: "arraybuffer"
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    var pdfFile = new Blob([data], {
        type: "application/pdf"
    });
    var pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdfFile);
    //window.open(pdfUrl);
    printJS(pdfUrl);
    //var printwWindow = $window.open(pdfUrl);
    //printwWindow.print();
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("Sorry, something went wrong")
});
```

Comment: Doesn't print PDFs on IE,  Edge or Firefox.

Comment: Tried this today using jQuery get to get the bytes of the pdf from server, then creating the blob and 'createOvjectURL' as above. PrintJS does not show the print dialog in this case. :)

Comment: can i print multiple pdf files with single click?

Comment: Just tried demo page. It prints in Firefox

Answer (score 13):

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/

for a live demo http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

it's probably what you want, but I can't see the point of this since modern browsers include such functionality, also it will run terribly slow on low-powered devices like mobile devices that, by the way, have their own optimized plugins and apps.

Comment: Pdf.js is also terribly slow when printing big documents, like 80MB+

Answer (score 6):

Cross browser solution for printing pdf from base64 string:

- Chrome: print window is opened
- FF: new tab with pdf is opened
- IE11: open/save prompt is opened

.

```
const blobPdfFromBase64String = base64String => {
   const byteArray = Uint8Array.from(
     atob(base64String)
       .split('')
       .map(char => char.charCodeAt(0))
   );
  return new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
};

const isIE11 = !!(window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob); // or however you want to check it

const printPDF = blob => {
   try {
     isIE11
       ? window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'documents.pdf')
       : printJS(URL.createObjectURL(blob)); // http://printjs.crabbly.com/
   } catch (e) {
     throw PDFError;
   }
};

printPDF(blobPdfFromBase64String(base64String))
```

BONUS - Opening blob file in new tab for IE11

If you're able to do some preprocessing of the base64 string on the server you could expose it under some url and use the link in `printJS` :)

Answer (score 6):

I used this function to download pdf stream from server.

```
function printPdf(url) {
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        // iframe.id = 'pdfIframe'
        iframe.className='pdfIframe'
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        iframe.style.display = 'none';
        iframe.onload = function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                iframe.focus();
                iframe.contentWindow.print();
                URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
                // document.body.removeChild(iframe)
            }, 1);
        };
        iframe.src = url;
        // URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
    }
```

Comment: Note that `iframe.style.display = none` breaks the rendering of some PDFs on my side. 
The workaround I found is setting `iframe.style.visibility = 'hidden'` and then `display: none` while the print window is open, with a timeout or something.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the pdf file using `fetch`, and print it with Print.js

```
fetch("url").then(function (response) {
    response.blob().then(function (blob) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function () {

            //Remove the data:application/pdf;base64,
            printJS({
                printable: reader.result.substring(28),
                type: 'pdf',
                base64: true
            });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  function printFile(url) {
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.src = url;
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    // Use onload to make pdf preview work on firefox
    iframe.onload = () => {
       iframe.contentWindow.focus();
       iframe.contentWindow.print();
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It will be easy this way:

```
function PrintPdf (pdf) {
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.style.display = "none";
        iframe.src = pdf;
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        iframe.contentWindow.focus();
        iframe.contentWindow.print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplification of @Nicolas BADIA's answer:

```
function printPDF (url)
{
    let pdfFrame = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe'));
    pdfFrame.style.display = 'none';
    pdfFrame.onload = () => (void pdfFrame.contentWindow.print());
    pdfFrame.src = url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that prints base64 encoded PDFs and works on current versions (as of 2023) of Chrome and Firefox. It's not dependent on external libraries and it's adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22695248/388994), which works with hosted files instead.

There's a caveat that this solution and the original answer's solution work only if the browser is set to open PDFs internally (the default behavior). If it's set to download them, it fails. You can use the [iframe workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46064696/388994), which works in both cases, but it doesn't print directly.

```
let printIframe
let blobUrls = []

async function printBase64PDF(data) {
    if (!printIframe) {
        printIframe = document.createElement('iframe')
        document.body.appendChild(printIframe)

        printIframe.style.position = 'absolute'
        printIframe.style.top = '0'
        printIframe.style.left = '-1000px'

        printIframe.onload = () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                printIframe?.focus()
                printIframe?.contentWindow?.print()
            }, 100)
        }
    }

    // convert base64 to a blob - using data URLs directly produces CORS errors
    const resp = await fetch(`data:application/pdf;base64,${data}`)
    const blob = await resp.blob()
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    blobUrls.push(url)

    printIframe.src = url
}
```

I wanted to do cleanup in an `afterprint` event, but it refused to fire no matter what, so I opted for a simpler solution - when the component that handles printing is destroyed, it removes the iframe and revokes all the blob URLs, freeing up memory.

```
function cleanUp() {
    printIframe?.remove()
    printIframe = undefined
    blobUrls.forEach(URL.revokeObjectURL)
    blobUrls = []
}
```

Comment: Offtopic: Consider undeleting https://stackoverflow.com/a/70569119/ I believe it might help some.