# Angulars : silently print PDF from client side

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developping an Angularjs Spring MVC application.
I am displaying a PDF in my browser (Chrome) like this :

```
window.open(location.pathname+'api/myReport/'+$scope.month.id,'_blank');
```

The PDF displays well.
Is there a way to silently print (instead of displaying it) the PDF to a chosen printer (chosen by its name) from client side? 
My server is on a VPS outside the company network and I can't access to local printers from the VPS.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print PDF directly from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239513/print-pdf-directly-from-javascript)

Comment: You utilize a really cool tool called [PrintNode](https://printnode.com/) that lets you install an application on an always running computer at your company, and then send the PDF to PrintNode. Right now it's in some sort of beta and free. Chrome Cloud Printing is another, though less worthy, alternative. PrintNode was better for me.