# How to print preview a PDF file in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using window.open() to open the file, It works as expected in Chrome and Edge, but on IE instead of opening into a window the file just downloads.

Is this a default behavior or do we have to use a JQuery plugin to open window to print preview that open in modal window?

Comment: probably default browser setting. What happens when you open a pdf directly in IE?

Comment: It asks for open or save but doesn't open . But on IE 7/ 8 it opens totally confused

Comment: Try [Jquery Print Js](https://gist.github.com/btd/2390721)

Comment: Would `window.print()` suffice? I would also recommend looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239513/print-pdf-directly-from-javascript