# How send a pdf file to print dailogue using script jQuery and markup tag object, without using Pdf plugin to the IE browser

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

Can you please explain How Load and send a file to print dialogue without opening it. It should work in IE[ie](/questions/tagged/ie) and Firefox [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) browser

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239513/print-pdf-directly-from-javascript