# Printing PDF from javascript in IE11

Tags: javascript, pdf

Is there any reliable way to print multi-page PDF from javascript in IE11 (preferably without having Acrobat Reader installed)? I see that it's fairly easy to do in Chrome, but I'm not able to find any working solution for IE. All solutions with embed and object tags are not working anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print PDF directly from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239513/print-pdf-directly-from-javascript)

Comment: All solutions with embed and object tags are not working anymore.

Comment: There are several answers in that question that do not use `embed` nor `object`. Have you tried those?

Comment: Yes, I've tried them. None of them work.

Comment: @AlexK Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54038393/6733608) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54037351/6733608) maybe you'll find it useful.