# Why is a blank page coming on the print screen when embed tag is used for pdf?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, printing, embed

I want to print PDF with using embed tag. PDF appers on the screen but blank page coming on the print screen. Why? and How can I solve this?

```
const width = window.innerWidth * 0.9;
const height = window.innerHeight * 0.9;
const content = `<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head><title></title></head>
        <body onload="window.focus(); window.print(); window.close();">
        <embed width="720" height="540" src="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" />
        </body>
        </html>`;
const options = 'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,width=' + width + ',height=' + height;
const printWindow = window.open('', 'print', options);
printWindow.document.open();
printWindow.document.write(content);
printWindow.document.close();
printWindow.focus();
```

Comment: I get a warning: "warning, the PDF is not fully loaded for printing" edit: wrapping the printing in `setTimeout()` works for me.

Comment: @ChrisG Can you write your answer please?

Comment: I have no idea how to figure out whether the PDF has fully loaded, and an answer should address that, not just suggest a random time delay.

Comment: you are right, thanks

Comment: If you are okay with using an iframe instead of an embed tag, you could try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22695248/1492977).