# Print pdf automatically from website without confirmation

Tags: javascript, php

I'm creating a cash register schedule. I would like the pdf file to be printed on the printer set up in the database once the order is placed, without a print preview. so far I have used php and javascript but I can use other languages ​​as well.
anyone know how i can do it?

Comment: check the answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239513/print-pdf-directly-from-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your browser.

Chrome (at least for windows) has a startup parameter `-disable-print-preview`. You can right click your Chrome Icon and add it as argument after `chrome.exe`.

Comment: Why downvote? What is wrong about this answer?

Comment: hank you very much for the advice, but if I wanted to do it independently of the browser?

Comment: @FrancescoGobbi I am afraid it is not possible. This is good, imagine any website could print without user interaction.