# Print a list of PDF files to Client's printer

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am writing a web application that will, amongst a lot of other things, produce a list of PDF files:

```
public JsonResult BulkPrintExemptions()
        {
            List<FileContentResult> retValues = new List<FileContentResult>();
            var results = db.Permits.Where(m => m.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Where(e => e.RecordDeleted == false).ToList();
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                retValues.Add(GetPDF(result, "Exemption"));
            }
            return Json(retValues, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The list will be a minimum of about 400 PDF documents, and the user wants to automatically print them without any interaction on her part.

Once I return that List of FileContentResults, how do I automagically send it to the user's default printer?

I am fairly certain I just need to loop through the list and call Acrobat Reader for each one; I'm just at a loss as to how to do that through javascript.

How do I do that?  Or, alternatively, I'm open to better options.

Full disclosure, to assist with options:

This is an MVC application in C#.  The enduser has Adobe Acrobat Reader (at least) installed, as it's a default on the "Office Desktop" image.

Edit to add:  The PDF files are coming from SSRS, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print PDF directly from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239513/print-pdf-directly-from-javascript)

Comment: This is not a great solution for many reasons, the simplest of which is that printing 400 documents via a web browser is going to tie up that browser window for a LONG time. And depending on what browser manufacturers do or don't decide, printing without user interaction may or may not continue to work in future browser releases. A more robust solution, IMO, would be to have your `BulkPrintExemptions` call queue up the PDFs to be printed somewhere (e.g. a DB table), and then on each client PC have a Windows service running that polls that queue and sends everything in it to the system printer.

Answer (score 1):

First, that sounds like a terrible idea on your user's part. This could potentially lead to locking up her computer while it processes that many print requests.

Second, it is possible. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239513/print-pdf-directly-from-javascript) has some options listed, and it looks like [Print.js](https://printjs.crabbly.com/) is probably your best bet. Some comments there said it didn't open the print dialog, so it may not require interaction on your user's part; but I sincerely hope it does, because allowing a website unlimited access to a printer with no user interaction sounds like a terrible idea.

Alternatively, if it prompts for every single one of those 400+ PDFs, if you can concatenate them into one 400+ page document then you'd only have one print dialog. Still probably slow/lock up her PC while processing that request.

Answer (score 0):

There are strict limits regarding what your WebPage can do on/to the Computer showing the WebPage. We used to be more lax. It was abused the heck out off. So it was fixed. But I doubt anyone was mad enough to ever allow JavaScript to send Print orders.

That being said it should be possible, using a Progamm or possibly even a Addon/Extension installed on the Client side.

You can [register Programms with specific Protocolls](https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/219031308-Launching-applications-using-custom-browser-protocols), same way you would with File Extensions. Indeed that is how those Steam Links on the Desktop work - they are URL's with the custom "steam:" Protocoll. And all browser register both the common Filenames and the common Protocolls.

That is about the best answer I can give you with such a broad question.