# Working on Chrome Browser on Desktop but on Android raises error: SecurityError Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: android, reactjs, google-chrome, desktop, printjs

Application running at domain https://lo93p.csb.app/

In **Chrome browser on Android,** when opening https://lo93p.csb.app/Test.pdf in **iframe**, it raises error:

**SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://lo93p.csb.app/" from accessing a cross-origin frame**

Same application is **working perfectly in Chrome browser on windows desktop.**

You can access this app as it is publicly available on CodeSanbox platform at https://lo93p.csb.app/

Target is React app with printing PDF silently on client-side.

Tried both dynamic iframe based on this [Print PDF directly from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239513/print-pdf-directly-from-javascript) and library printJS (https://printjs.crabbly.com/)

Problem occurs not only on CodeSandbox but also on actual app hosting environment when accessing app in Chrome browser on Android.

Comment: Thought got some attention within a few hours. Any suggestions to get attention from stackoverflow community?

Comment: Hi, any solution did you get related this ? facing the same..

Comment: No not yet, search continues!

Comment: found any solution yet?