# Print a pdf file without using iframe trick

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to print a pdf file from a URL.

what I have done so far:

```js
      fetch(
        "https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/flask-cors/latest/flask-cors.pdf"
      )
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.blob();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          const localPdf = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
          const printFrame = document.getElementById("pdf");
          printFrame.setAttribute("src", localPdf);
          printFrame.onload = () => {
            printFrame.focus();
            printFrame.contentWindow.print();
          };
        });
```

```js
 <iframe id="pdf" name="pdf" />
```

It works without any problem. **BUT** in the chrome browser there is an option in `chrome://settings/content/pdfDocuments`
when `Download PDF files instead of automatically opening them in Chrome` is active I got this error :

`SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost:44310" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`
I got this error even when the file is in the same origin.

I didn't find any solution. Is there any other way to print a file?

Comment: why do you change the chrome's setting if originally it works without problem ?

Comment: @KenLee we can't tell to our customers don't change your browser setting.

Comment: @morteza Have u tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54038393/8092354

Comment: @adzo261 there is an open issue on printJS repo about this problem https://github.com/crabbly/Print.js/issues/316