# Possible to embed javascript in PDF and have it fire when PDF is opened in Browser Window?

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-analytics

Is it possible to embed a piece of javascript in a `.pdf doc`, and have the script fire when the `.pdf` is opened in a browser? ... It should not require any user interaction inside the doc (like a click, etc) -- just **fire the script when the .pdf is opened** in a browser.

I would like to embed some analytics beacons or conversion tracking tags inside .pdfs, if this is possible.

Thanks in advance if you know any possible solutions! :)

Comment: Check this comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/9640245/1501643

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acrobat JavaScript has a method (`launchURL()`), which would send the message to the URL. You can run the according command in a Document-Level JavaScript (which is embedded in the document, and gets executed when the document opens). More to this method and its implication can be found in the Acrobat JavaScript documentation, which is part of the Acrobat SDK documentation, and downloadable from [the developer section of the Adobe website](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/documentation.html).

However, it requires that the PDF viewing component of the webbrowser supports Acrobat JavaScript. And that limits you pretty much to Acrobat (Reader) using a browser which still supports the Acrobat Browser Plug-in, and the Acrobat Browser Plug-in has to be active. The PDF viewing components built into the browsers are too dumb, and your code will not get executed.

On the plus side, this approach also works when the document is opened outside of a browser; sole condition is that the PDF viewer does support Acrobat JavaScript, and the `launchURL()` method.

Comment: Max, this is quite interesting, can you please add links to resources describing these methods more complexly?

Comment: @JakubKriz: I added the link to the Acrobat JavaScript documentation to the answer; thanks for reminding me to do that.

Comment: Good answer, Max. So in most cases, no, it is not possible -- unless you render the pdf with some Acrobat Javascript AND the user has an an active Acrobat Browser plugin. Thanks! ... looks like event clicks will have to be my solution. Thanks

Comment: @RoweMorehouse: That's the approach from a technical point of view. There is, however an ethical/privacy point of view, which puts the idea to track the user (behind his back, of course) into serious questions.

Comment: One problem with event clicks is that if a user lands directly on the PDF as they can from Google SEO, nothing is tracked.

Answer (score 1):

Aside the interesting Acrobat answer of Max, AFAIK it isn't possible to run JavaScript in a PDF without user interaction.

To track these interactions with PDFs in the past, we have instead relied on event clicks on the PDF view link instead.

However, these days consider server side tracking by sending a Measurement Protocol hit when the PDF resource is viewed, ideally taking the same cid from a cookie in the same session.

Comment: The Document Open and the PageOpen of the page the document opens with events are kind of without user interaction (unless you count "opening the document" as user interaction). And the privileged Start Application event as well (unless you count "starting the application" as user interaction…). But, yes, when the document is opened, triggering an Acrobat Action (for example "running a JavaScript") is done directly or indirectly by the user.

Comment: I guess I haven't run into it before as it uses Acrobat only, so only a % of users will have be able to be tracked - its not in my Firefox for example https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/view-pdf-files-firefox-without-downloading-them